# Will Safari ever support WebExtensions api?

Tags: safari, firefox-addon-webextensions, safari-extension

My web extension works with Chromium browsers, Firefox, Edge, but as I understand - it is impossible now just to open the same codebase with Safari browser?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Update 2021**

The Safari support for WebExtensions was released in 2021 and is available from Safari 14 (shipped with macOS Big Sur). WebExtensions for Safari are published in the App Store. Documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/safari_web_extensions

**Original answer**

We cannot possibly know this for sure, but Apple is currently not planning to support (a version of) the WebExtensions API. The name of the standard/specification is Browser Extension.

Apple is not part of the W3C group which attempts to make a cross browser standard: https://www.w3.org/community/browserext/participants

For more general info on the Browser Extension W3C working group, see
https://browserext.github.io/browserext

The provisional spec can be found here: https://browserext.github.io/browserext/

Comment: Also note, as your link correctly proves, the standard is currently called "browser extension". "WebExtension" seems to be the FIrefox-specific term for it (I assume in order to differentiate it from their older extension APIs etc.)

Answer (score 5):

In [macOS Big Sur](https://www.apple.com/macos/big-sur-preview/features/), Safari will support the WebExtensions API:

> New support for the WebExtensions API and migration tools allows developers to bring Chrome extensions to Safari — letting you personalize your browsing experience with new Safari extensions from your favorite developers.

Comment: fast and to the point (true of your answer false of apple :)

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry I didn't see your answer because I was updating my original answer.

Comment: Thank you, but still we will need to pay 100$ per year to publish our extensions in their store? It is already possible to publish?